# Python: Overwriting of squish methods which are injected after runtime

Tags: python, squish

I am developing a squish suite with python which should allow users without software development skills to record testcases for gui applications.
Some of the squish methods should changed/extended to fit our special needs, and therefore I write a wrapper which overwrites the squish methods.

Therefore it would be best, if the user has to change as few as possible from the recorded code.
I don't want that the user has to add "mywrapper." before every method call.

So I thought I just add 
"from mywrapper import *"

With mywrapper containing methods with the same name as the squich methods, for example:

```
def waitForObjectItem(object, item, timeout=None):
    // do additional stuff
    return squish.waitForObjectItem(object, item, timeout)
```

The problem is that (from the squish website):

> Squish functions and member are injected into the squish module at runtime after the test script has started/attached to an application.

Therefore the imported code of mywrapper will not be used.

How can I force that my code will be executed instead of the squish code without further changes of the testcase recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to import "mywrapper" within the main function instead of at the top of the document.
Therefore it will not be imported until the function is executed and therefore only after the injection of the juice methods.